# Phone Call Task Error on WP8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, task

I have a problem with debug my app.There is no eror, I debug the app on device it start's but when I tap the button debug error!
that's how i use it:

In .xaml file:

```
<Button Name="taxi1" Content="Call Taxi 1" Click="taxi1_Click" />
```

in .xaml.cs file:

```
private void taxi1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
 PhoneCallTask call = new PhoneCallTask();
call.DisplayName = "Calling Taxi 1";
  call.PhoneNumber = "1411111";
call.Show();
 }
```

and i added:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
```

I think what I'm doing it wrong is that i use this function for several times the only thing that is changing is the name of taxi:

private void ***taxi2***_Click (....)

and the call.DisplayName="***Calling Taxi 2***";

and call.PhoneNumber = "***1422222***";

Maybe I should use only one function like

```
        private void PhoneCall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
          string number="";
          HttpUtility.UrlEncode((sender as Button).Tag.ToString());
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("number", out number))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(number))
            {
         PhoneCallTask call = new PhoneCallTask();
        call.DisplayName = "Taxi";
          call.PhoneNumber = number;
        call.Show();
         }
}
}

and <Button ....... Tag="141111" .. />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just one thought, do you have permission added in manifest for this to work ? if so, writing what error is actually being thrown would be helpful in order to help you

Comment: I mean Properties > WMAppManifest.xml / Capabilities just to be clear

Comment: ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER should be added?

Comment: @ZaraGheorghe yes, add that capability

Answer (score 0):

**ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER** should be added